# How does CakePHP 3.x ORM know which cache file to read from without explicitly defining it?

Tags: caching, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

CakePHP 3.5.13

In a Controller method I'm caching a database query as follows:

```
$substances = TableRegistry::get('Substances');
$query = $substances->find()->limit($limit)->offset($offset);
$query->cache(function ($query) {
    return 'substance_results_' . md5(serialize($query->sql()));
});
$this->set('data', $query->all());
```

This generates a cached file (we're using Redis for caching in this application) containing the results of the query. For example, I can see the following in Redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
3) "cake_redis_substance_results_cb799f6526c148d133ad9ce9245b23be"
4) "cake_redis_substance_results_dbc7b0b99dff3ab6a20cbdfbbd09be8c"
```

If the same query (`$query`) is executed again, Cake will read the contents of the appropriate cached file. **How is this possible given that we're not telling it which key to read the cached data from?** We are telling it the name of the key to *write to* but not *read from*.

To further illustrate this let's say I did:

```
$query->cache(function ($query) {
    return 'foo_' . md5(serialize(time()));
});
```

Here I've made a key that's completely different and isn't based on the SQL that's being executed. No part of the code tells it which key corresponds to which query.

The documentation (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-loaded-results) on Caching Loaded Results does not explain this with respect to the ORM. It says:

> The cache method makes it simple to **add** cached results to your custom finders or through event listeners.
>
> When the results for a cached query are **fetched**...

It's telling you how to write (add) to the cache, but not read (fetch) from it with respect to the ORM.

I've read sections of the documentation which tell you how to read from the cache in a general, non-ORM-specific way (using `Cache::read($key)`) but that's completely separate to having the ORM do it automatically. In the case of `Cache::read($key)` you're having to supply a key (`$key`) which tells it which cache file to read the data from - I can understand this as you're explicitly telling it which key to read. But that's not the case with the ORM and query objects.

Please can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CookBook most likely doesn't mention additional requirements, because there aren't any.

The cache key for *writing* must of course be the same as the cache key for *reading*, anything else wouldn't make any sense, ie the query will use whatever you pass to the `QueryTrait::cache()` method for both, reading and writing, which means that you *are* explicitly defining the key for reading, right there in the closure that you are passing.

Check [**the method description**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.13/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php#L136-L171), it pretty much says the same thing:

````
/**
 * Enable result caching for this query.
 *
 * If a query has caching enabled, it will do the following when executed:
 *
 * - Check the cache for $key. If there are results no SQL will be executed.
 *   Instead the cached results will be returned.
 * - When the cached data is stale/missing the result set will be cached as the query
 *   is executed.
 *
 * ### Usage
 *
 * ```
 * // Simple string key + config
 * $query->cache('my_key', 'db_results');
 *
 * // Function to generate key.
 * $query->cache(function ($q) {
 *   $key = serialize($q->clause('select'));
 *   $key .= serialize($q->clause('where'));
 *   return md5($key);
 * });
 *
 * [...]
 *
 * @param false|string|\Closure $key Either the cache key or a function to generate the 
 *   cache key. When using a function, this query instance will be supplied as an argument.
 *
 * [...]
 */
````

Everytime a query is being executed, it will check if you've passed a cache key, and evaluate and use it to read and write cached results accordingly. Consequently you must ensure that the cache key is "static" in order for the whole query caching thing to be of any use.

You can use a closure to build the key dynamically, but the result must be static, ie for the same query it must generate the same key everytime it's being invoked. There's a reason that the `QueryTrait::cache()` method not only accepts a closure, but also a string!

I've mentioned it before, this happens in [**`\Cake\Datasource\QueryTrait::all()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.13/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php#L284-L293) and [**`\Cake\Datasource\QueryCacher::fetch()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.13/src/Datasource/QueryCacher.php#L72), have a look at the source to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I really feel that's something that should be mentioned in the documentation. Essentially the answer is that in the first set of code I posted, `serialize($query->sql())` deals with both writing to and reading from the cache, because `$query->sql()` is the SQL string that is to be executed, and therefore only changes when the query itself changes. This means it's able to find (read) a cached key if the same SQL is run more than once because a matching key will exist.

Comment: @Andy It certainly wouldn't hurt to add additional description. If you create an issue over [**at github**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues), someone will probably take care of it.